# Run same script with two different arguments simultaneously

Tags: python, compilation, simultaneous

I have a script that computes 1000 integrals of a function defined in the script.
This is fairly long to run, so I want to start the script again with another function **before** the first script finished running.
Can these simultaneous runs with different arguments interfere?
Or is the code compiled once, and then the script can be modified while running?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: If by "start the script" you mean running something like `python my_script.py` in command line, you can drop a process in the background by adding an ampersand at the end of it, like so `python my_script.py &`. Then you can continue running anything else (or it again at the same time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can these simultaneous runs with different arguments interfere?

No.

> Or is the code compiled once, and then the script can be modified while running?

Yes.

Source code is usually only relevant for things like debugging and tracebacks, it's forgotten once a file has been imported or started running.